# 3 images on first line then 2 images on the second line underneath

Tags: html, css

I want to have 3 images on the first line and 2 on the second. I have this code but it has 2 on top and 3 on the bottom.

```
<ul>
  <li><img src="./icons/User_Management.png" /></li>
  <li><img src="./icons/User_Management.png" /></li>  
  <li><img src="./icons/User_Management.png" /></li>  
  <li><img src="./icons/User_Management.png" /></li>  
  <li><img src="./icons/User_Management.png" /></li>
</ul>

* { box-sizing: border-box; }
    ul { 
      list-style: none; 
      font-size: 0; 
      margin: 0; 
      padding: 0; 
      text-align: center; }

    li { display: inline-block; padding: 10px;}

    li:nth-child(1), li:nth-child(4) {
      width: 50%;
    }
    li:nth-child(4) { text-align: right; }
    li:nth-child(2) { text-align: left; }
```

I want the two bottom images to be centred with the three images at the top.

Expected Result - 3 Images on first row and 2 on second row
Actual Result - 2 Images on first row and 3 on second row

Comment: 2 flexboxes stacked, 2 images in the first, 3 in the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Flex:

```css
#container{
  width: 550px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#container > img{
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
</div>
```

Comment: This works however I want the two bottom images to be centred with the three images at the top.

Comment: Changed it to a flexbox answer

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this which is an amazing CSS tool. Use CSS grid.

```
//HTML
<ul class="grid">
  <li><img src="./icons/User_Management.png" /></li>
  <li><img src="./icons/User_Management.png" /></li>  
  <li><img src="./icons/User_Management.png" /></li>  
  <li><img src="./icons/User_Management.png" /></li>  
  <li><img src="./icons/User_Management.png" /></li>
</ul>

//CSS
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

Comment: Works however I want the two bottom images to be centred with the three images at the top

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

Just adjust the widths and use the appropriate `nth-child`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 33.3%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

li:nth-child(4),
li:nth-child(5) {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/140/100" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/140/100" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/140/100" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/140/100" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/140/100" /></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: hi @Paulie_D, if you don't mind can you check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58415903/8620333 it's a perfect duplicate and it was reopened (don't know why). Even the OP was able to find a solution based on my duplicates (see comment section). Thanks.